# Does an infinite spin chain with infinitely many pure states exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Let ($\rho_n)_n$ be a sequence such that $\rho_n$ is a state on $\bigotimes_{n}\mathbb{C}^{2} = (\bigotimes_{n-1}\mathbb{C}^{2}) \otimes \mathbb{C}^{2}$ and for all $n$, we have that: $\rho_{n-1} =$ Partial trace of $\rho_{n}$ over $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

i.e, $\rho_{n-1} $ is obtained from $\rho_{n} $ by tracing out its last qubit.

Can such a sequence have infinitely many pure and infinitely many non-pure (properly mixed) states in it? i.e, can there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $\rho_{n} $ is a pure state and $\rho_{n} $ is a non-pure state?

Comment: Not an expert, but this feels like a very under-constrained problem. Tracing is a many-to-one operation, and so there are an infinite number of ways to work backwards from any particular $\rho_1$ and build a sequence that satisfies the above; thus, you probably can't say anything about $\rho_n$ without specifying exactly how this sequence is assembled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just take
$\rho_n = (|0\rangle\langle0|)^{\otimes n}$.

*Edit:* As to your updated question: Yes, just take $\rho_{2n}=(|\omega\rangle\langle\omega|)^{\otimes n}$ and $\rho_{2n+1}=\rho_n\otimes(\tfrac121\!\!1)$, with $|\omega\rangle=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Here, each $\rho_n$ is pure. I have added an extra condition to my original question now.

Comment: @Quantum Updated.